# Can't get email from ApplePay PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController

Tags: ios, swift, applepay

I am using ApplePay and requiring email as contact information. When I am trying to get email, the email result I get is "Shipping" which I don't even know where it comes from.

I have required email field in the request, and filled in email information.

```
request.requiredShippingAddressFields = PKAddressField.PostalAddress | PKAddressField.Email
```

Here is the code:

```
func paymentAuthorizationViewController(controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController!, didAuthorizePayment payment: PKPayment!, completion: ((PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus) -> Void)!) {

    let address: ABRecord! = payment.shippingAddress

    let emails: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(address, kABPersonEmailProperty).takeRetainedValue() as ABMultiValueRef
    if ABMultiValueGetCount(emails) > 0 {
        let email = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(emails, 0).takeRetainedValue()
        NSLog(email)  //Here prints "Shipping"
     }
    ...
 }
```

Is this the right place to get email? If not, what is the correct approach?

---

Trying to get phone number (kABPersonPhoneProperty), the result printed as "Shipping" as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a subtle "typo" in your code :). `ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex` copies the label for the entry (which is "Shipping"). You'll want the value using `ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex`.

```
  let emails: ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(address, kABPersonEmailProperty).takeRetainedValue() as ABMultiValueRef
  if ABMultiValueGetCount(emails) > 0 {
    let email = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emails, 0).takeRetainedValue() as String
    NSLog(email)  //Here prints your email address!
  }
```

Comment: Please convert the above answer to Objective C.

Answer (score 2):

For iOS9 and newer

```
let email = payment.shippingContact?.emailAddress
```